# Slack refusing to start

Tags: 20.04, firefox, slack

from 30 minutes ago on slack refuses to start on my 20.04 box. Last thing i did before it stopped working was updating firefox to 102.0 but i'm not confident if this is related to it.

I downloaded the recent slack 4.27.154 deb package from their website and installed it through through `apt install`, however it still refuses to start.

Here's the console output:

```
> slack 
Initializing local storage instance
[winston] Attempt to write logs with no transports {"error":{},"level":"error","message":"Unable to create logs directory"}
[winston] Attempt to write logs with no transports {"level":"info","message":"\n╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗\n║      Slack 4.27.154, linux 5.15.0-10033-tuxedo on x64      ║\n╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝"}
[winston] Attempt to write logs with no transports {"meta":{"shouldUseNewBackend":false,"loggerInstanceCount":1},"level":"info","message":"Configured logger via"}
[winston] Attempt to write logs with no transports {"meta":{"NODE_ENV":"production","platform":"linux","type":"browser","timeZone":"Europe/Berlin","PACKAGE_MANIFEST.productName":"Slack","PACKAGE_MANIFEST.version":"4.27.154","PACKAGE_MANIFEST.commit":"8956995","PACKAGE_MANIFEST.branch":"HEAD"},"level":"info","message":"Predefined values for process"}
[winston] Attempt to write logs with no transports {"level":"debug","message":"getLogger: Winston backend does not support child logger"}
```

I also noticed a strange error when trying to get the help information:

```
❯ slack --help
A JavaScript error occurred in the main process
Uncaught Exception:
TypeError: b is not a function
    at y (/usr/lib/slack/resources/app.asar/dist/boot.bundle.js:1:32588)
    at Pt (/usr/lib/slack/resources/app.asar/dist/boot.bundle.js:1:7238)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/slack/resources/app.asar/dist/boot.bundle.js:1:5038)
    at Object.D (/usr/lib/slack/resources/app.asar/dist/boot.bundle.js:1:4765)
    at /usr/lib/slack/resources/app.asar/dist/boot.bundle.js:32:16305
    at /usr/lib/slack/resources/app.asar/dist/boot.bundle.js:32:16414
    at /usr/lib/slack/resources/app.asar/dist/boot.bundle.js:32:16418
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/slack/resources/app.asar/dist/boot.bundle.js:32:16440)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1118:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1173:10)
```

Anyone has any idea what the problem is? I'm not finding anything on this stuff in the web.

Comment: Just in case this helps, try restarting the computer.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi, tried it. didn't.

Comment: Seeing the same issue here on both 20.04 and 18.04

Comment: Also seeing this on 22.04.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**UPDATE : July, 8th **

Available working version now from slack is : 4.27.156

https://downloads.slack-edge.com/releases/linux/4.27.156/prod/x64/slack-desktop-4.27.156-amd64.deb

---

**OUTDATED proposal :**
I confirm also that this version of Slack seems to have problems.

as explained by  @Iam Strad you can install Slack from snapcraft, unfortunately, it will probably not be enough as it brings you the same version 4.27.154 2022-06-27.

But with snap you can find an older version of slack that is still functional  until a better version is published.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install snapd
sudo snap install slack --channel=insider/edge
```

or

```
sudo snap refresh slack --channel=insider/edge
```

it should bring you version 4.25.1 that could be a temporary workaround .

```
> snap info slack

name:      slack
summary:   Team communication for the 21st century.
publisher: Slack✓
store-url: https://snapcraft.io/slack
(...)
channels:
  latest/stable:     4.27.154 2022-06-27 (63) 110MB -
  latest/candidate:  ↑                              
  latest/beta:       ↑                              
  latest/edge:       ↑                              
  insider/stable:    –                              
  insider/candidate: –                              
  insider/beta:      –                              
  insider/edge:      4.25.1   2022-04-01 (61) 108MB -
installed:           4.25.1              (61) 108MB -
```

Comment: Directly from slack support, they propose those two alternatives which are closed from what was proposed on this page : 
If you're on the Snap Store version you should be able to do this via ```sudo snap revert slack```


If you are on the .deb, you can download 4.26.1 here: 
https://downloads.slack-edge.com/releases/linux/4.26.1/prod/x64/slack-desktop-4.26.1-amd64.deb

Comment: it fixed the problem after running `top` and killing Slack processes.

Comment: Just received the upgrade to 4.27.156 but it seems to be still broken. :-(

Comment: 4.27.156 is working after I killed all stale `slack` processes. :tada:

Answer (score 11):

Downgrading seems to work, as a workaround for now;

```
sudo apt install slack-desktop=4.26.1
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you. Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: $ sudo apt install slack-desktop=4.26.1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '4.26.1' for 'slack-desktop' was not found


also tried slack=4.25.1

Comment: Thx but didn't WFM (Ubuntu 20.04). After downgrade, running slack from command line no longer outputs `[winston] Attempt to write logs with no transports` errors after `Initializing local storage instance`, but slack still doesn't start. Worrying. Don't want to reboot at the mo. so I'll use slack from my browser until I next reboot.

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround you could use slack with chromium. In a terminal you could execute:
`chromium --app=https://yourslackworkspace.slack.com`

If that works, create your own desktop file in /home/user/.local/shares/applications for easy access:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Chromium Slack chat
Comment= Slack chat app
Exec=chromium --app=https://yourslackworkspace.slack.com
Icon=/home/user/.local/share/applications/slack.png
Path=
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
StartupWMClass=yourslackworkspace.slack.com
```

I'm running slack with this config, calls, huddle etc works out of the box

Answer (score 0):

For those who have the it installed on apt-get:

In my search for an older version to roll back to, I ended up scouring the [flathub code](https://github.com/flathub/com.slack.Slack/blob/master/com.slack.Slack.json) for a url for downloading an older .deb and came across:

`https://downloads.slack-edge.com/releases/linux/$version/prod/x64/slack-desktop-$version-amd64.deb`

Replacing the $version with a version number found on [the slack release notes page](https://slack.com/release-notes/linux) did the trick.

Example:

```
wget https://downloads.slack-edge.com/releases/linux/4.26.1/prod/x64/slack-desktop-4.26.1-amd64.deb
```

and then

```
sudo dpkg -i slack-desktop-4.26.1-amd64.deb
```

UPDATE:
I could have probably saved a lot of trouble by following [the dowgrade path](https://github.com/flatpak/flatpak/wiki/Tips-&-Tricks#downgrading) for flatpak apps.

Answer (score 0):

I found these problems, my slack was installed by *.deb and yesterday I updated to version 4.27. I solved it by updating the nvidia video card drivers, using the drivers from the nvidia-driver package.