# How to fix slack on Ubuntu 20.04.4?

Tags: 20.04

On my Ubuntu 20.04.4 machine slack suddenly did not work anymore. I followed the advice given [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45133562/can-any-one-say-how-to-install-the-slack-in-ubuntu14-04-and-while-trying-this-wa) (main answer), but now when I open a terminal and enter `slack` I get exactly the following output:

(no output at all. I get back to the command prompt).

So how to fix this urgent problem?

Comment: No, when I try to run `sudo apt install slack-desktop=4.26.1` as suggested, I get an error `E: Unable to locate package slack-desktop`.

Comment: The second suggestion seems to work

Answer (score -1):

Based on [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1416364/slack-refusing-to-start) the following procedure seem to have worked:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install snapd
sudo snap refresh slack --channel=insider/edge
```

(You might `kill` any running `slack` instances, but it will tell you). After that `slack` starts again.

Comment: That is literally the accepted answer to the duplicate question.